# Javascript - Rugby point calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator, points

I'm just in the very early learning stages of Javascript and am messing around with basic functions/variables.  I wrote out this rugby point calculator and am just interested if anyone can give me hints about how to improve it, especially in getting rid of the prompts and using parameters instead.

```
function calculateRugbyPoints (){

   tryTotalPoints = tries * tryPointValue;
   conversionTotalPoints = conversions * conversionsPointValue;
   penaltiesTotalPoints = penalties * penaltyPointValue;
   totalPoints = conversionTotalPoints + penaltiesTotalPoints + tryTotalPoints;
   return totalPoints;
}

var tries = prompt ("How many tries have been scored?");
var tries = parseInt (tries);
var tryPointValue = 5;

var conversions = prompt ("How many conversions have been scored?");
var conversions = parseInt (conversions);
var conversionsPointValue = 2;

var penalties = prompt ("How many penalties have been scored?");
var penalties = parseInt (penalties);
var penaltyPointValue = 3;

calculateRugbyPoints()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve this by using arguments in your `calculateRugbyPoints()` method. At the moment all your variables are global. Realistically you should use global variables when they're being shared across multiple functions. However, in your case you only have one function, so using arguments/parameters should be used. Also, you should define the variables which are specific to the function (like `tryPointsValue` etc...) within the function itself, not outside of it.

```
function calculateRugbyPoints (tries, conversions, penalties){
   // Initializing (setting equal to) the variable names to their values (integers/numbers)
   let tryPointValue = 5;
   let conversionsPointValue = 2;
   let penaltyPointValue = 3;

   // Initializing more vriables to their computed values
   let tryTotalPoints = tries * tryPointValue;
   let conversionTotalPoints = conversions * conversionsPointValue;
   let penaltiesTotalPoints = penalties * penaltyPointValue;

   let totalPoints = conversionTotalPoints + penaltiesTotalPoints + tryTotalPoints;
   return totalPoints;
}
```

As you may have noticed, in the function above I used `let`. `let` is very similar to `var`, however, when we create a variable using `let` its *scope* is defined to where it was created. This means none of the variable defined within the `calculateRugbyPoints` function can be accessed outside of the function.

Now that you have created your function to accept parameters, you can must *pass through* parameters when calling your function:

```
calculateRugbyPoints(tries, conversions, penalties);
```

Now looking at how you get user-input. At the moment, you are re-initializing your variables like so:

```
var tries = prompt ("How many tries have been scored?");
var tries = parseInt(tries); // <--- var shouldn't be here
```

This isn't a good idea, as you are redefining the variable using `var` each time. You should only use `var` when you are defining the variable for the first time. Thus, you're above code should look like this:

```
var tries = prompt ("How many tries have been scored?");
tries = parseInt(tries);
```

This can even be simplified even further to:

```
var tries = parseInt(prompt ("How many tries have been scored?"));
```

or even:

```
var tries = +prompt ("How many tries have been scored?");
```

Here the `+` means convert whatever we enter through the prompt into a number (integer, float, etc). But do note, `parseInt` and the `+` operator do behave in slightly different ways. But for what you're trying to achieve, you don't need to worry too much about it.

There are also many ways to receive user input. One other way from using `prompt`s would be to create a HTML form, and use javascript to get the numbers passed through in that form.

Keeping all this in mind, your final program should look something like this:

```js
function calculateRugbyPoints(tries, conversions, penalties) {
  // Initializing (setting equal to) the variable names to their values (integers/numbers)
  let tryPointValue = 5;
  let conversionsPointValue = 2;
  let penaltyPointValue = 3;

  // Initializing more vriables to their computed values
  let tryTotalPoints = tries * tryPointValue;
  let conversionTotalPoints = conversions * conversionsPointValue;
  let penaltiesTotalPoints = penalties * penaltyPointValue;

  let totalPoints = conversionTotalPoints + penaltiesTotalPoints + tryTotalPoints;
  return totalPoints;
}

var tries = parseInt(prompt("How many tries have been scored?"));
var conversions = parseInt(prompt("How many conversions have been scored?"));
var penalties = parseInt(prompt("How many penalties have been scored?"));

alert("Your points are: " +calculateRugbyPoints(tries, conversions, penalties)); // alert the returned value of the function calculateRugbuPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to render in a HTML page or use simple form to get this information, otherwise you will have to use prompt for simple javascript, using html that for sure will increase your learning curve and will be helpful to use properly the calculator, and ofcourse will be more user friendly.

I always use a online tool as https://codepen.io/pen/ or https://jsbin.com/ to test my snippets on js.

```js
function calculateRugbyPoints (){
var tryPointValue = 5;
var conversionsPointValue = 2;
var penaltyPointValue = 3;
var tries = parseInt(document.getElementById("tries").value);
var conversions = parseInt(document.getElementById("conversions").value);
var penalties = parseInt(document.getElementById("penalties").value);
    

   tryTotalPoints = tries * tryPointValue;
   conversionTotalPoints = conversions * conversionsPointValue;
   penaltiesTotalPoints = penalties * penaltyPointValue;
   totalPoints = conversionTotalPoints + penaltiesTotalPoints + tryTotalPoints;
   console.log(totalPoints);
  alert(totalPoints);

  return totalPoints;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <div>
<form onsubmit="calculateRugbyPoints()">
  Enter Tries: <input id="tries" type="text"><br>
  Enter Conversions: <input id="conversions" type="text"><br>
  Enter Penalties: <input id="penalties" type="text"><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>  
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you calculate the totalpoints have a check if the provided input is a valid number or not, if so just use parseInt and pass them to the calculateRugbypoints function.

```js
var calBtn = document.getElementById('calculateBtn');
    calBtn.addEventListener('click', calculatePoints, false);
    
    function calculatePoints() {
     let tries = document.getElementById('tries'),
         conversions = document.getElementById('conversions'),
          penalties = document.getElementById('penalties');
            
        tries = tries.value;
        conversions = conversions.value;
        penalties = penalties.value;
        
        if(!validNumber(tries) || !validNumber(conversions) || !validNumber(penalties)) return;
        console.log(calculateRugbyPoints(parseInt(tries,10), parseInt(conversions, 10), parseInt(penalties, 10)));
    }
    
    function calculateRugbyPoints (tries, conversions, penalties){
       let tryPointValue = 5;
       let conversionsPointValue = 2;
       let penaltyPointValue = 3;
       // Initializing more vriables to their computed values
       let tryTotalPoints = tries * tryPointValue;
       let conversionTotalPoints = conversions * conversionsPointValue;
       let penaltiesTotalPoints = penalties * penaltyPointValue;

       let totalPoints = conversionTotalPoints + penaltiesTotalPoints + tryTotalPoints;
       return totalPoints;
    }
    
    function validNumber(num) {
      return num && !isNaN(num) && Number(num) === parseInt(num, 10)
    }
```

```html
<div>
    Enter Tries: <input id="tries" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    Enter Conversions: <input id="conversions" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    Enter Penalties: <input id="penalties" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <button id="calculateBtn">
        calculate
    </button>
</div>
```